# HTML Sanitizer for .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, html-sanitizing

I'm starting a project that will be public facing using asp.net mvc. I know there are about a billion php, python, and ruby html sanitizers out there, but does anyone have some pointers to anything good in .net? What are your experiences with what is out there? I know stackoverflow is a site done in asp.net that allows freeform HTML, what does it use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use C# to sanitize input on an html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188870/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-sanitize-input-on-an-html-page)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/safe-html-and-xss/

Comment: +1, but that links to a page full of refactorings by different people (I was hoping for something a little more release-like)

Answer (score 25):

#### [HtmlSanitizer](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/)

Source: https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

A fairly robust sanitizer. It understands and can clean inline styles, but doesn't have a parser that can deal with <style> blocks, so it strips them. It's certainly up to and probably beyond the level that Microsoft's AntiXSS was at, before it was abandoned.

Comment: This sanitizer looks much better (at least from the documentation) than Microsoft's solution.

Answer (score 4):

**[HtmlRuleSanitizer](https://github.com/Vereyon/HtmlRuleSanitizer)**

Based on your question I have the following suggestions:

- You want to allow free form HTML, so you need a solution to be able to specify a set of tags, attributes and/or CSS classes which are allowed.
- By allowing free form HTML it is likely that you'll also have to deal with malformed HTML because users make errors (deliberate or not). You thus need a solution built on a tolerant parser such as the [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).
- You'll want to take a white listing approach because a black listing sanitizer does not protect your from any new HTML specifications. In addition it is very hard to guarantee that a black list covers all cases in the first place due to the size of the HTML specification.

I faced the same problem and built HtmlRuleSanitizer which is a white listing rule based HTML sanitizer on top of the Html Agility Pack.

Answer (score 3):

there is a c# version [here](http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/03/04/a-html-sanitizer-for-c/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one built by microsoft. http://wpl.codeplex.com/

```
var cleanHtml = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtml(unsafeHtml);
```

Comment: This appears to be getting some really bad reviews so I wouldn't recommend it anymore.

Comment: it doesn't work at all and didn't remove onmousover event from a Tag

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragments

sanitize input by parsing the HTML fragment,to use this sanitizer for rich content to ensure that it does not content any harmful script and it is safe to be displayed on the browser.For the text input(not rich content) to use AntiXss.HtmlEncode or any other equivalent html encoder.Here is the Sample for rich content.

```
 string mal = "<IMG NAME = 'myPic' SRC = 'images / myPic.gif' onerror='alert(1)' onerror='alert(1) ><div bottommargin = 150 ondblclick = 'alert('double clicked!')' >< p > Double - click anywhere in the page.</p> </div> ";
                var cleanHtml = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(mal);
                Console.Write(cleanHtml);
                Console.Read();
```

**Note: Download AntiXSS library fron nugetpackage manager and include this namesapce**
**Microsoft.Security.Application in the souce code**;

Comment: The sanitization method is is `Microsoft.Security.ApplicationSanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(string)` .. And the Nuget can be installed by executing `Install-Package AntiXSS` in the Package Manager Console.

Comment: Is AntiXss deprecated today?