# How to make a C# whitelist/BlackList

Tags: c#, html

I want to check the HTML tags the user is using in a rich html editor I have. I am not sure though how to do this in C#.

Should I be using Regex and what HTML tags should I be blacking listing/white listing?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple whitelisting approach:

```
string input = "<span><b>99</b> < <i>100</i></span> <!-- 99 < 100 -->";

// escape & < and >
input = input.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("<", "&lt;");

// unescape whitelisted tags
string output = input.Replace("&lt;b&gt;", "<b>").Replace("&lt;/b&gt;", "</b>")
                     .Replace("&lt;i&gt;", "<i>").Replace("&lt;/i&gt;", "</i>");
```

Output:

> `&lt;span&gt;<b>99</b> &lt; <i>100</i>&lt;/span&gt; &lt;!-- 99 &lt; 100 --&gt;`

Rendered output:

> <span>**99** < *100*</span> <!-- 99 < 100 -->

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tags are entered as single string like here on StackOverflow, you'll want to split the string into individual tags first:

```
string[] tags = "c# html  lolcat  ".Split(
    new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

A white-/blacklist can be represented using a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) storing the tags:

```
HashSet<string> blacklist = new HashSet<string>(
    StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) { "lolcat", "lolrus" };
```

Then you'd have to check if one of the `tags` is on the list:

```
bool invalid = tags.Any(blacklist.Contains);
```

Comment: I think the OP is talking about HTML tags/elements.

Comment: lol yes. Hmm but I guess it could almost be the same basic idea? Everything of course is not on the same line though so not sure how to do a fast search on the stuff.

Comment: Now that I read it again... I guess you're right. But there's no lolcat tag in HTML, so I'd have give up my example if I change my answer now. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). I haven't tried it to skip tags, but it could certainly find tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
string StringWhitelist(string StringToSanitize, string AllowedCharacters)
{
    if (StringToSanitize.Length != 0 && AllowedCharacters.Length != 0)
    {
        List<char> UnsanitizedString = StringToSanitize.ToCharArray().ToList();
        List<char> Whitelist = AllowedCharacters.ToCharArray().ToList();
        string SanitizedString = StringToSanitize;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < UnsanitizedString.Count; i++)
            SanitizedString = Whitelist.IndexOf(UnsanitizedString[i]) == -1 ? SanitizedString.Replace(UnsanitizedString[i].ToString(), string.Empty) : SanitizedString;
            
        return SanitizedString;
    }
    else
        return null;
}

string StringBlacklist(string StringToSanitize, string NotAllowedCharacters)
{
     if (StringToSanitize.Length != 0 && NotAllowedCharacters.Length != 0)
     {
          List<char> UnsanitizedString = StringToSanitize.ToCharArray().ToList();
          List<char> Blacklist = NotAllowedCharacters.ToCharArray().ToList();
          string SanitizedString = StringToSanitize;

          for (int i = 0; i < UnsanitizedString.Count; i++)
              SanitizedString = Blacklist.IndexOf(UnsanitizedString[i]) != -1 ? SanitizedString.Replace(UnsanitizedString[i].ToString(), string.Empty) : SanitizedString;

          return SanitizedString;
     }
     else
         return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
StringWhitelist("Ciao", "abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyz"); // Output: ao (because "C" and "i" are not in the whitelist)
StringBlacklist("Ciao", "Ci"); // Output: ao (because "C" and "i" are in the blacklist)
```