# prevent user to enter script tags in asp.net mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a login view in asp.net-mvc. i want that user cannot able to enter  tag in username or password field

Comment: Why? What kind of tags? My password can be <password>...

Comment: thats why i want any solution in which user can input any character,  but default if i enter <scipt> tag in username it just blast and yellow screen comes

Comment: Fraz your questions says the opposite, you should correct the question title and text, maybe changing prevent for allow, and user cannot for the users are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want preventing the user from entering tags? Leave him enter whatever he wants. Why preventing someone from having a password such as `<script>alert('hello');</script>` - it looks like a pretty strong password. Personally I hate web sites limiting my choices for a password.

Just make sure that you encode everything you are outputting inside the views:

So instead of:

```
<div>Hello <%= Model.Username %></div>
```

Always use:

```
<div>Hello <%= Html.Encode(Model.Username) %></div>
```

or:

```
<div>Hello <%: Model.Username %></div>
```

if you are working with ASP.NET 4.0

Also, as pointed out by @Jab in the comments section, in order to accept such input from the user you might need to decorate the controller action that will handle the submission with the [`[ValidateInput(false)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493062(v=VS.100).aspx) attribute.

Comment: To accept input of <script> tags you will have to use [ValidateInput(false)] on any screen where the user inputs the password. Otherwise you get the YSOD.

Comment: Html.Encode(Model.UserName) is working fine when im trying to display UserName but whenever a user try to login and enter <script>alert("asdf")</script> in username textbox yellow screen comes which says "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (username="<script>alert("asdf"...")" I have try [ValidateInput(false)] but it doesnt work

Comment: You need to put it on the controller action to which you are posting: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/08/ValidateInputAttributeASPNETMVCPotentiallyDangerousRequestFormValues.aspx

Comment: Thanks Darin but i have tried this and its not working in my case

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason regular sanitisation approaches  [As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188870/how-to-use-c-to-sanitize-input-on-an-html-page) will not work with MVC?