# ASP.NET MVC text-editor light-weight

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textarea

It should be free. Easily integrable with asp.net mvc. Extremely light-weight. It must sanitize the input.

for example, say if the user enters

> hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

It must not break the formatting of the page!

if the user enters some nasty html or maybe any html at all or any javascript code, it should reject that.

It would be awesome if it did some sort of cuss-word checking too, but that is not a requirement. 
It can be jquery based.

Before you feel tempted to mark this question as duplicate, do check whether other questions are very old or something like that.

Comment: And what will you do when a user disables scripting or alters the editor's client-side code to disable your sanitization? You need to be doing this on the server. (in addition to the client)

Comment: Ok, that's nice.  Did you want to ask a question?

Comment: @Andrew, I did not mean the validation should/must occur on client-side.

Comment: The editor would be on the client side, so that's where "it" would be doing the validation.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of RTEs that can be easily integrated into an asp.net page.There are many that are jquery based. See [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors&ei=KW7QTuD2MMXIgQfns5TNDQ&usg=AFQjCNESFNqTgGze8SsCeKhfpUGboajCaw) I use server side code to sanitize. There are a number of classes that can be used to sanitize html. Run the user entered text thru the sanitizer to strip the markup.I am using  http://roberto.open-lab.com/2010/03/04/a-html-sanitizer-for-c/ 
Jeff Atwoods code is [here](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html)
Also see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188870/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-sanitize-input-on-an-html-page)