# WebBrowser with limited tags support in C#

Tags: c#, editbox

I need a editBox in c# that only shows and edits formatted texts(bolded,colored,...) and supports RTL and I can to get Html code from inputed text.

So used WebBrowser and enabled designMod on it. it's very good but it also shows unwanted contents (images,links,tables,...) if user pastes in it or drops to it.

I also used RichTextBox,But it have above problem and it don't provide html code for me.

If anyone can help me to implement a webbrowser control that cat not accepts some tags?
Sorry for bad English!!

Comment: Essentially, you are asking [how to use C# to sanitize input on an html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188870/how-to-use-c-sharp-to-sanitize-input-on-an-html-page)

Comment: thanks,If I understand correctly, I must manage paste and drop actions and remove unwanted contents by regex but I don't know how to do it.The input can be image or anything else and I want markup texts only.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the tags you don't want before you push it to your webbrowser. I don't believe there exists some premade control for this.

Comment: I searched in internet but i did not find any way to filter out the tags in HtmlDocument.

Comment: @Ali.M, Paolo has already provided you a link. You just need to adapt it to your needs. If you need just formatting of the text, you need to whitelist those tags (i, b, ...) and it will strip rest of the tags. http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html Have you at least tried it or just expecting some copy&paste style of code?