# How to save HTML to database and retrieve it properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, xss

Learning security these days :)
I need to allow users to enter text in a form and allow them some HTML tags: bold, italic, list etc. and to prevent them to add some dangerous JavaScript code.
So I have used [this whitelist implementation](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/whitelist-santize-htmlagilitypack/) to sanitize HTML. 
But I am still confused about how to save and display it in the right way.
So here what I did:
Model:

```
public class Post
    {
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Post model)
        {
            // Decode model.Data as it is Encoded after post
            string decodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(model.Data);
            // Clean HTML
            string sanitizedHtmlText =  HtmlUtility.SanitizeHtml(decodedString);

            string encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sanitizedHtmlText);
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextAreaFor(a=>a.Data)
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

So when I post a form I see:

```
<p>Simple <em><strong>whitelist</strong> </em>test:</p>
<ul>
<li>t1</li>
<li>t2</li>
</ul>
<p>Image:</p>
<p>&lt;img src="http://metro-portal.hr/img/repository/2010/06/medium/hijena_shutter.jpg" /&gt;</p>
```

Becaouse of `<p>&lt;` I think that I need to decode it first:

```
<p>Simple <em><strong>whitelist</strong> </em>test:</p>
<ul>
<li>t1</li>
<li>t2</li>
</ul>
<p>Image:</p>
<p><img src="http://metro-portal.hr/img/repository/2010/06/medium/hijena_shutter.jpg" /></p>
```

Then I sanitize it against whitelist and I get sanitized HTML:

```
<p>Simple <em><strong>whitelist</strong> </em>test:</p>
<ul>
<li>t1</li>
<li>t2</li>
</ul>
<p>Image:</p>
<p>
```

1) Should I save it like this in database?
2) Or I need to Encode this result and then save it to database (encoded bellow)?

```
&lt;p&gt;Simple &lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;whitelist&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;/em&gt;test:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;t1&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;t2&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Image:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
```

Here I am confused if I put it on the view like this:

```
@Model.Data
```

I get this on the view:

```
&lt;p&gt;Simple &lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;whitelist&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;/em&gt;test:&lt;/p&gt; &lt;ul&gt; &lt;li&gt;t1&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;t2&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;p&gt;Image:&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;
```

or

```
<p>Simple <em><strong>whitelist</strong> </em>test:</p> <ul> <li>t1</li> <li>t2</li> </ul> <p>Image:</p> <p>
```

So what to do to display this HTML properly (bold, list etc.)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The rule of thumb is the following:

1. Store in your database the RAW HTML without any encodings or sanitizings. A SQL server doesn't care if you store some string containing XSS code.
2. When displaying this output to your page make sure that it is sanitized.

So:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Post model)
{
    // store model.Data directly in your database without any cleaning or sanitizing
}
```

and then when displaying:

```
@Html.Raw(HtmlUtility.SanitizeHtml(Model.Data))
```

Notice how I used the Html.Raw helper here to ensure that you don't get double HTML encoded output. The `HtmlUtility.SanitizeHtml` function should already take care of sanitizing the value and return a safe string that you could display in your view and it will not be further encoded. If on the other hand you used `@HtmlUtility.SanitizeHtml(Model.Data)`, then the `@` razor function would HTML encode the result of the `SanitizeHtml` function which might not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Aha... clear :) so after post basically I can save this to database `<p>This is <strong>safe</strong> text and <em>danger</em> follows &gt; &lt;script&gt;alert('attack');&lt;/script&gt;</p>` and just use SanitizeHtml on the view. I thought that I must not save html tags in database. This value I get is passed model from view to Create method (it adds &qt, lt etc).

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. There's nothing wrong in storing raw HTML in your database.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov How do i get `HtmlUtility.SanitizeHtml()` method. I do not know what to reference. I did some google search and found here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.data.html.htmlutilities.aspx) that `HtmlUtility` is only available for Windows and Windows Phone. How can get this referenced in my MVC Web Project?

Comment: For sanitizing HTML (i.e. remove tags not in whitelist) see [Is there a good solution for a C# html sanitizer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208860/is-there-a-good-solution-for-a-c-sharp-html-sanitizer)

Answer (score 2):

To framework 4.5, Using MVC 5, use 
            @Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item.ADITIONAL_INFORMAtION))

Answer (score 1):

You can save HTML file in database by datatype VARBINARY(MAX) for htmlcolumn .

> 1. Convert a html file in binary file ([code project link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/682841/how-to-convert-a-html-file-in-binary-file))
> 2. insert data in a column like this sample code :

```
Declare @HTML   Varbinary(MAX) = Set HTML Varbinary code here 

Insert into table_name (htmlcoulmn)
Value @HTML
```

> 3. Load data on the database ,when you need load file , you should convert htmlcolumn to Nvarchar(max) by this code :

```
Select CAST(htmlcolumn as nvarchar(MAX)) As HTMLCODE
FROM Table_Name
```

If this solution has a problem, thank you for writing me a comment.

**I hope you for the best**