# Asp .net MVC Razor - Posting HTML from form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm looking for some guidance\back practice, etc on a project i'm currently working on.

The site has a form, which allows the user to create an email template.
The email template is simply a text area with a wysiwyg editor (bootstrap-wysihtml5).

So the text area will have basic html tags so the user can format the look of the email.

My question is : What is the best\safest way to handle posting back the HTML from the text area to avoid any script attacks, etc?

If its any help i do have a whitelist of HTML tags for the emails.

Comment: Possible dup of [How to save HTML to database and retrieve it properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662766/how-to-save-html-to-database-and-retrieve-it-properly) answer's by Darin Dmitrov so you know it's good!

Comment: Have a read of http://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/antixss-4-2-breaks-everything/ and look at the workaround that uses HTMLAgility pack and AntiXss to provide a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about safety than do one of these 2 things:

- Allow a Whitelist of tags and limit the UI. Again, this will be lot of work and lot of XSS testing.
- Or accept markdown formatting and convert markdown to HTML on your server

For second option, you can use http://kevo.io/pagedown-bootstrap/ or any such markdown aware editor. The toolbar can help users who are unaware of markdown syntax.

Comment: Thanks i think that ill have a look at the markdown option

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't forget to upvote if you find this answer useful!

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming email templates will be created a authorized interal users.*

use `[AllowHtml]` attribute for the Model property of your TextArea field. That shoul dbe good enough for your requirement.